# Get number of integer values in string and store them in array

Tags: c, arrays

Is there a way to get how many `int` values are in a string?

For example, user inputs:

```
"1 2 3 4 5"
```

I will create an array of `int`, `array[n]`, where `n` is the number of integers found in the array and then store 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in the `array`.

Is there a method to store them one by one? I know `sscanf()` can return the number of successfully found and stored values if we assign a limit of `%d` in the parameters, but... If it's an unknown size of values?

Comment: Just parse a string.

Comment: a) Count the values,then allocate the array, then rescan the values and put them in the array, or b) allocate the array from the heap and grow it as you go. There are several ways to find the individual numbers ... strtok, sscanf, or strspn/strcspn (as well as strpbrk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char *input = "1 2 3 4 5";
    int len = 0, n = 0;
    char *p = input;
    while(sscanf(p, "%*d%n", &len)==0){
        ++n;
        p += len;
    }
    int i,array[n];
    for(i=0, p=input;i<n;++i, p += len){
        sscanf(p, "%d%n", &array[i], &len);
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I love you >~<!! Thanks! :DD